# Katalon Studio creating element with webDriver not recognised when used in Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, katalon-studio

I'm trying to use the executeJavascript method in Katalon Studio, and having written a couple lines of code that look really similar to that in the documentation example:

documentation example: 
[image]

my script: 
[image]

I have also imported WebElement in my script:

[image]

However, when I run my test I get this error message:

```
Test Cases/Forms/Test1 - fill in maintenance request form FAILED because (of) Unable to execute JavaScript. (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: element is not defined
(Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d6988c0745c24c8858745aaaec01ef),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
System info: host: 'Nikkis-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:18e2:b2c7:8b31:3164%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: com.kms.katalon.selenium.driver.CChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.35.528157 (4429ca2590d698..., userDataDir: /var/folders/fl/d70hxqb520v...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 66.0.3359.181, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 05ebb4c39e0862af7f3893c442527a3b)

Test Cases/Forms/Test1 - fill in maintenance request form.run:65
```

then, I updated my selenium, chrome driver and java, but I still get this error:

```
Unable to execute JavaScript. (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: element is not defined   (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z' System info: host: 'Nikkis-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:18e2:b2c7:8b31:3164%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_102' Driver info: com.kms.katalon.selenium.driver.CChromeDriver Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.38.552518 (183d19265345f5..., userDataDir: /var/folders/fl/d70hxqb520v...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version:
66.0.3359.181, webStorageEnabled: true} Session ID: 2c4f4643acb4d1c0a106ac0fb9e31254)
```

I don't understand why i am still getting this error, and how i can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: element is not defined
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to communicate with the **Browsing Context** i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- You are using *chrome=66.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.7.1** of *2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z* which is almost *half year* older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_102** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK* **v8u102**, *Selenium Client* **v3.7.1** , *ChromeDriver* version **v2.35** and the *Chrome Browser* **v66.0**

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u171**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.12.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: you said '...implies that the ChromeDriver was unable to initiate/spawn a new WebBrowsing Session i.e. Chrome Browser session.', but a new chrome browser did open up to run the test - is this not what you meant??

Comment: Hmmm, typo got corrected. Updated my Answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: could you please describe how to carry out this step: Clean your Project Workspace through your IDE and Rebuild your project with required dependencies only.

Comment: @user74843 This step is to be performed from the IDE i.e. _Eclipse_, _PyCharm_, _SublimeText3_ to clear the IDE cache. I am not sure about _Katalon-Studio_ but there must be an option to **Rebuild** the entire project afresh.

Comment: hay, I updated my selenium, chrome driver and java. you can see the updated versions are being used in the edited post (i have edited the post with updates). However, I am still getting the error message...

Comment: @user74843 Remove the `blockquotes` from the error trace logs within your question else the logs gets truncated and debugging becomes difficult

Comment: sorry, okay. btw, i'm not sure if this makes a difference, but if i try to execute a line in my script like this: WebUI.executeJavaScript("alert('This is an alert')", null), it works! Does this change anything?

Comment: @user74843 Your _JDK_ version is still **'1.8.0_102'**  which is pretty ancient :)

Comment: oh no! How can i change the JDK version? I downloaded the newest version - 1.8.0_172, but when I run a test using katalon studio it still seems to be using 1.8.0_102. I know how to change selenium and the chrome driver version, using this article https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Update+or+Replace+Web+Browser+Drivers+and+Selenium, but I don't know how to change the java file..